# Kentico: How do I create my own template

Tags: asp.net, kentico

Ho do I create my own master template page in kentico 7? Must I use the Portal Engine?

Answer (score 1):

You can use portal engine or ASPX or mixed templates - what is more convenient for you. Here you can find more information:

Portal templates: http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/devguide/creating_a_new_page_template.htm
ASPX: http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/devguide/creating_a_new_aspx_page_template.htm (and two chapters below is the mixed mode described).